# Count the probability of one event based on the previous condition using group_by and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, tidyverse

I have a large data set that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(group=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), event=c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1), time=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4))

  group event time
1     A     0    1
2     A     1    2
3     A     1    3
4     A     0    4
5     B     1    1
6     B     1    2
7     B     1    3
8     B     1    4
```

I want to count for each group the probability to see "1" or "0" given the event at the previous time point. For example in group A we see that when "0" occurs then "1" follows with 100% probability but when "1" occurs then "0" or "1" follows with 50% probability each. In the group B we see one event dominating. When "1" occurs then "1" with 100% probability.

I would like my data preferentially to look like this

```
group  event probability
 A     0-1       100
 A     0-0         0
 A     1-1        50
 A     1-0        50
 B     0-1         0
 B     0-0         0
 B     1-1        100
 B     1-0         0
```

Any help or comment are appreciated.

Comment: good point Ronak, I ll update my question based on your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(group, time) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(event_next = lead(event)) %>% 
  slice(-n()) %>% 
  count(group, event, event_next) %>% 
  group_by(group, event) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#   group event event_next     n  prop
#   <chr> <dbl>      <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 A         0          1     1   1  
# 2 A         1          0     1   0.5
# 3 A         1          1     1   0.5
# 4 B         1          1     3   1
```

Comment: It might be safer to add `arrange(time)` before the first mutate in case the data don't come properly ordered.

Comment: Agree. I have updated the answer. Thanks!